# Copy content between floppy disks on Apple II

Tags: apple-ii, floppy-disk

I own an Apple IIe with the Apple DuoDisk device. I've been trying to find out if it is possible to copy content from a floppy disk inserted into the disk 1 slot into a floppy inserted on the disk 2 slot. I haven't found any information.

Does anyone know if this is possible? Would I need any specific software to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Duo Disk behaves exactly like two Disk II drives connected to a single Disk II controller card from a software point of view.

Do you want to copy a whole, unprotected, 5.25" disk? You can e.g. use COPYA from the Apple DOS 3.3 master disk, just say RUN COPYA at the "]" Applesoft BASIC prompt after booting from the DOS 3.3 master. If you use ProDOS instead of Apple DOS, the system utilities or the fast copy program (I forgot the exact names) are your friend. You can select either from the Startup menu of the ProDOS 2.0.3 master disk after booting it.

If you want to copy single files, you can use FID, also found on the DOS 3.3 master disk. Say BRUN FID to start it. On ProDOS, use the system utilities again.

For copy protected disks, get a copy of COPY II PLUS.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The idea is to copy a whole unprotected 5.25" disk into a blank one, yes. Then I guess I need to get a copy of DOS or ProDos, as I don't have a floppy with any of those. Correct?

Comment: Correct, you need a disk with an OS (usually DOS or ProDOS) on it to do anything actually useful with your Duo Disk.

Comment: You should add that COPYA is one of the slower alternatives; programs like COPY II PLUS can do it a lot faster.

Comment: @dirkt, sure, I was just saying COPYA because it is so widely available, I'm assuming many people who rediscover an old stack of apple hardware will have DOS or ProDOS master disks but don't have ADTPro or something like it to transfer other programs.